# CollectionView cell height is not automatically resizing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, mvvmcross

So I am encountering some issues with a UICollectionView I have in my Xamarin iOS project.

The cells for the CollectionView are not expanding with the label in them. The label in the cell has **lines** set to 0 and the following constraints:

- (top, bottom, leading, trailing) to superview
- Height >= 10

In my **ViewDidLoad()** I setup the CollectionView as follows:

```
var source = new CustomCollectionViewSource(collectionView);
        collectionView.Source = source;
        collectionView.SetCollectionViewLayout(new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        {
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
            EstimatedItemSize = new CGSize(collectionView.Frame.Width, 10)
        }, false);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainViewController, MainViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).For(v => v.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.DataSource);
        set.Apply();
```

and my **CollectionViewSource**

```
 public class CustomCollectionViewSource : MvxCollectionViewSource
{
    public IList<Item> Messages { get; set; }

    public override void ReloadData()
    {
        var list = (ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Item>).ToArray();
        Messages = list;
    }

    public CustomCollectionViewSource(UICollectionView collectionView) : base(collectionView)
    {
        collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(CustomCollectionViewCell.Nib, CustomCollectionViewCell.Key);
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(CustomCollectionViewCell.Key, indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell;
        cell.DataContext = Messages.ElementAtOrDefault(indexPath.Row);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the cells be the width of the collection view and for the height to be flexible; however, whenever I populate the cells, I always get something like this: [image: UICollectionView Cells that are cutoff][image]
The cells are cutoff and have an ellipses at the end. I've read online that the constraints must be right to dynamically resize, so is there something I'm missing?

I also read that to get a calculated height for each cell I can load the nib of the cell, populate it, then set the size manually in a custom UICollectionViewDelegate. Cool idea, but I could find any working examples for Xamarin iOS.

Please let me know if there is something I'm missing or any other info you require. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the height constraint and change your bottom constraint to >= 10

Comment: Setting the bottom constraint to less than or equal to 10 did it!!!!!!! Guess my constraints were off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Make your label support multiple lines by

```
textLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
textLabel.Lines = 0;
```

2.Set the cell estimated height

```
cell.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
```

**Things to note:**

- To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of
  constraints and  views (with defined heights) to fill the area
  between the content view’s top  edge and its bottom edge.
- If your views have intrinsic content heights, the system uses those
  values.  If not, you must add the appropriate height constraints,
  either to the views  or to the content view itself.

Comment: Now the cells are little squares. Still not expanding to fit the label. if I turn off clip to bounds on the cell, I can see the whole label. Don't know if that helps? Also, there is no `cell.EstimatedItemSize` in the CollectionViewSource

Comment: can you send me a screenshot of it ?

Comment: updated post. The text I've inputed is much longer than those in the box.